# Convert a method name to bean name at runtime?

Tags: java, javabeans, aop

I am working with BeanBinding a lot in my current project and so I have code that looks like...

```
TypeA objA;
TypeB objB;
Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ, 
    objA,   BeanProperty.create("X"),
    objB,   BeanProperty.create("X"))
    .bind();
```

Where `objA` and `objB` are instances of classes that have a `setX()` method. The problem comes in that if I refactor `setX` to `setY` then I need to hunt down these string property names. I realize I can create static final strings for property name but if I can get the compiler to do the work for me, all the better.

Ideally, what I would like to be able to do is...

```
TypeA obja;
TypeB objB;
Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ, 
    objA,   BeanProperty.create( Magic.returnBeanName(TypeA.class).getX() ),
    objB,   BeanProperty.create( Magic.returnBeanName(TypeB.class).setX() )
    .bind();
```

It would seem this could be possible via some code synthesis and/or aspects.

Comment: A complete shot in the dark, but maybe `returnBeanName` can use javassist to create an object that takes each getter method, modifies its return type to String and returns the property name? Seem kind of crazy, but sounds fun to write.

Comment: @Jeremy: I thought about your suggestion but in order for Eclipse and other refactoring tools to work, the method signature must stay the same which would be a real issue for setters since they produce voids and also for final methods since they are "special"

Comment: I didn't mean you should modify the bean itself. I meant you could make a copy of the bean class, with method names exactly the same as your bean, but with those methods returning the name of the property instead.

Comment: @Jeremy: right, but the moment you change what they return (it to a string) then Eclipse sees them differently. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't literally mean "change". I'll post code in an answer...

Answer (score 1):

A complete shot in the dark, but maybe `returnBeanName` can use javassist to create a different class similar to the bean, except that it modifies the return types of the getters to String and returns the property name?

For example, if your bean looks like this:

```
public class Foo{
    private int x;

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x){
        this.x= x;
    }
}
```

Then dynamically create a *different* class that looks like this:

```
public class FooMeta{
    public String getX(){
        return "x";
    }
}
```

Seem kind of crazy, but sounds fun to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [instrumentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html): create a [java agent](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/07/javaagent-option.html) using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to access your classes at compile time and generate the needed classes/interfaces/methods. It's not easy and you should invest time to learn about java instrumentation, JVM bytecode and the ASM library but you can do wonders with it.

Comment: Yeah, I actually know how to do but them problem comes in that I now need to register the generated classes back to eclipse so it can handle refactoring. One reason I was hoping someone would just say that some lib/plugin already existed.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like what Jeremy Heiler suggested in my open source project, [Funcito](http://funcito.googlecode.com), which you could [browse the source code](http://code.google.com/p/funcito/source/browse/src/org/funcito) to see an example of what needs to be done to use byte code manipulation, using either Javassist or CGLIB.

The general idea is that you use a code enhancer from Javassist or CGLIB to proxy the class of interest as a subclass which has a method interceptor. You intercept the method call and record the name of the method invoked, and then turn around and extract that invoked method name and use it as you like.  The semantics for your use would be very similar to the Funcito usage semantics, which is close to what you posted as your ideal.